# VBA - How to select tab on webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I've seen a couple of questions similar to this but have had no success.

I am trying to write a piece of code after navigation to a secure webpage which will click on a tab and load this data (there is no URL behind the tab so cannot use that). I need to click on the sales tab which has the ID overview. Can someone please help me write a line of code which will find this object and click on it. [HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7vXD.jpg)

Many thanks

fyi i tried stuff like

```
ie.document.getelementbyID("overview")(0).Click
```

Comment: Please try and use the snippet tool provided to insert your html. It helps us give accurate answers. It is the icon in the toolbar when writing your question that looks like a page with <> on.

Comment: Please don't edit new html for a different question into an old question. It invalidates the answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select

```
ie.document.querySelector("div[id=overview]")
```

So if clickable try:

```
ie.document.querySelector("div[id=overview]").Click
```

Or simply

```
ie.document.querySelector("#overview").Click
```

That is assuming the element isn't inside a form/frame/iframe. Can't tell from the small HTML sample though.

Comment: thats the only code relating to the tab names. the rest relates to the information on the corresponding tab. Operational Offices is the default so doesn't matter if this i click this or not it will still show :) but when i swap that for '#overview' (the sales tab) this works perfectly! you sir/madam (think i have to include neutrual nowadays too) are my new fav person! - really got to learn this queryselector stuff i tried it but not with the href stuff :'(

Comment: Sorry. I had just noticed and was just posting update!

Comment: Enjoy this https://flukeout.github.io/ along with https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Good solution as always.

Comment: Hey Qharr are you able to help me i got another webpage (this time its through a CRM system that uses HTML that references JavaScript though the code is confusing (to me) and I cannot figure out how to click the relevant tab.
If so i've attached the HTML code to the orginal post at the start, I want to click on the NBT Order Intake tab tried the query select and normal .click but to no avail.

Comment: Did you try ie.document.querySelector("#home_tab_name_98").Click  ?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, yes i did try that, no success get the error message no object identified.

Comment: Can you please use the rollback facility to revert this question to how it was so the answer remains valid for future users. Then post a new question. It will be a lot easier for me/others to help you that way as there are bound to be new questions for us to bounce back and forth and comments. To confirm, I want to help. Just in the right way.

Comment: Done, new question posted :)